# DXA 2.0 import failed

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-2.0

We are facing one issue while importing DXA 2.0 . We did following steps to import DXA:

1. Copied the DXA Application Data Definition.xml file to `%TRIDION_HOME%\config\ImportExport\ApplicationData\`
2. Run the `ttm-prepare.ps1` script

   1. given dxa staging URL
   2. Not provided discovery URL
3. Run the cms-import.ps1 script with below parameters:
   `.\cms-import.ps1 -importType all-publications -cmsUrl https://URL/ -cmsAuth Basic -cmsUserName "Administrator" -cmsUserPassword "password"`

We are getting below error:

```
Tridion.ContentManager.InvalidUriException: No items found for WebDAV URL(s): /webdav/1
00%20Master/Building%20Blocks/System/Configuration%20components/Default%20sorting%20config.xml.
   at Tridion.ContentManager.UrlConversion.Convert()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Session.GetTcmUri(String uri)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Session.GetObject(String uri, LoadFlags loadFlags)
   at SDL.Web.Extensions.EventSystem.SortingOptions.CopyDataForSortingToMetadata.ReadConfiguration(Component component)
   at SDL.Web.Extensions.EventSystem.SortingOptions.CopyDataForSortingToMetadata.DoWork(Component obj, SaveEventArgs arg
s, EventPhases phase)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.EventSubscription.DeliverEvent(IEnumerable`1 subjects, TcmEventArgs eventArgs
, EventPhases phase)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.EventSystem.DeliverEvent(IEnumerable`1 subjects, TcmEventArgs eventArgs, Even
tDeliveryPhase deliveryPhase)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.EventSystem.DeliverEvent(IdentifiableObject subject, TcmEventArgs eventArgs,
EventDeliveryPhase deliveryPhase)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Save(Boolean checkInAfterSave)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.ImportAction.<>c__DisplayClass30_0.<SaveItem>b__0(Boolean isRetry)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Process.<>c__DisplayClass35_0.<InvokeInErrorHandler>b__0(Boolean isRetry)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.AbortErrorHandler.Invoke[T](Func`2 function, LocalizableMessage message, Boole
an retryAvailable, Boolean isCritical, UserReply additionalUserReplyOptions)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Process.InvokeInErrorHandler[T](Func`2 function, LocalizableMessage message, B
oolean retryAvailable, Boolean isCritical)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.ImportAction.SaveItem(IdentifiableObject item, IdentifiableObjectData deltaObj
ect)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.CreateImportAction.Perform(IdentifiableObjectData itemData)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItem(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Dictiona
ry`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean specialImport)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItems(IList`1 items, Boolean specialGroupImport)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.Import(String packageName)
[Information] Transactional import failed . No changes were committed to
SDL Web Content Manager.
```

Could you please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working after commenting custom Event extension.

Comment: Please accept your own answer, then.